# Batch script to download many files via http?

Tags: windows, http, scripting, batch-file

I have a list of urls (over 100) of patch files from various sources that I need to download.

I need to create a batch script that will download these files and dump them all into the same directory.

I do not have administrative privileges on the system I need to download to, so it needs to be batch or similer solution.

I would love it if it would echo any errors to the screen and keep rolling on to the next download.

Comment: You've specified the end goal, but you didn't really specify what part you need help with. Are you just looking for someone to write it for you?

Comment: Ryan, sure. Or a link to one that I can hack.

Comment: Oh, sorry! When I first read it I was thinking "bash" scripting. I'm a noob at batch scripting and wouldn't be of much help. My bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.httrack.com/page/2/en/index.html

HTTrack can be run just as a EXE.

It does a great job, and can do everything your looking for.

Comment: This worked, but sadly not on the network I was trying to do it from as the proxy caused issues.

Answer (score 3):

These should help:
http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html
http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm

Answer (score 0):

WGET or CURL are good choices for this task.  Using CURL to pick up the latest copy of Httrack through your proxy:

```
curl -x myproxy:8081 -u robw:mysecretpassword --proxy-ntlm http://download.httrack.com/cserv.php3?File=httrack.exe
```

Comment: Does curl work on windows?

Comment: Yes - there has been a win32 port available for years.  See:  http://curl.haxx.se/   for a version.